# Nested mysql query in each loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, underscore.js

So all i want to do is to make a query to get all id's from the database and then i want to do my method for the id and update the row in the database.

So i created this code. But all it is doing is to get the ids and do not the nested query with the insertString1.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var _ = require("underscore");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'myHost.net',
    user     : 'myUser',
    password : 'myPassword',
    database : 'myDatabase'
});


connection.query('SELECT * FROM `idmarkethash`', function (error, results) {
    _.each(results, function (row) {
        // here i want to calculate the new values of the row
        // This insert query is just an example
        var insertString1 = "UPDATE idmarkethash SET " +
                    "Price=" + mysql.escape(2.00) + ", " +
                    "Gradient=" + mysql.escape(2.00) + ", " +
                    "LastUpdated=" + mysql.escape("2015-08-31 00:00:11") + " " + 
                    "WHERE Id=" + mysql.escape(181) + ";";
        connection.query(insertString1, function (error1, result1) {
            console.log(result1);
        });    
    });
});
```

I tried the same with the async package:

```
var async = require('async');
// Packages are all included.

connection.query('SELECT * FROM `idmarkethash`', function (error, results) {
    async.each(results, function (row, callback) {
        // here i want to calculate the new values of the row
        // This insert query is just an example
        var insertString1 = "UPDATE idmarkethash SET " +
                    "Price=" + mysql.escape(2.00) + ", " +
                    "Gradient=" + mysql.escape(2.00) + ", " +
                    "LastUpdated=" + mysql.escape("2015-08-31 00:00:11") + " " + 
                    "WHERE Id=" + mysql.escape(181) + ";";
        connection.query(insertString1, function (error1, result1) {
            console.log(result1);
            callback();
        });    
    });
});
```

With debugging i could see that the declaration of insertString1 is called, but the second query is not fired / or the loop continues without recognizing the second query.

Comment: Why iterate the `UPDATE` operation over the resultset of the `SELECT` operation, rather than simply perform one single `UPDATE` for the entire table?

Comment: does it return row? also you may try it with async.waterfall function because you will wait for the first query to return result so that you can execute your first query.